# Delete unused shapes in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, shapes

I've got a shape detection with OpenCV in Python going on; bolts and nuts. I take a picture, make it binary, and detect edges. Now the white area is always grainy because of dust and grime. My detection uses the largest areas as parts, which works great. But how can I delete the thousands of objects caused by dust? 
In short, I want to reduce the array of shapes to only the biggest ones for further processing.

Comment: Post a link to an example image. From your binary image get the contours. Then select the largest contour. Then draw a white filled contour on a black background image the same size as your input as a mask. Then use numpy to blacken everything in your image that is black in your mask.

Comment: It is not necessarily useful to *delete* the extra "objects". Just ignore them when doing further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that as per my comment above using Python/OpenCV.

From your binary image get the contours. Then select the largest contour. Then draw a white filled contour on a black background image the same size as your input as a mask. Then use numpy to blacken everything in your image that is black in your mask.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("coke_bottle2.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold using inRange
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology closing to fill black holes and smooth outline
# could use opening to remove white spots, but we will use contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (25,25))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get the largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw largest contour as white filled on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros((hh,ww), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, 255, -1)

# use mask to black all but largest contour
result = img.copy()
result[mask==0] = (0,0,0)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("coke_bottle2_threshold.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("coke_bottle2_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("coke_bottle2_background_removed.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image (contains small extraneous white regions):

[image]

Mask Image (only the largest filled contour):

[image]

Result:

[image]